# AQTime Allocation Profiler - VerificationException on PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute

Tags: asp.net, .net, profiling

I am trying to run the AQTime Allocation Profiler against my ASP.NET web application. I am able to run the Performance Profiler just fine but when I run the Allocation Profiler, I get  the following exception.

System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.

It seems to be called when a method “Autofac.Integration.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()” inside Autofac.Integration.Mvc (an extention to the IoC container I am using) is called. It looks like this method is registered to be called early in the startup web process for ASP.NET via the PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs file found here.

http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/src/Source/Autofac.Integration.Mvc/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs

In looking up this exception, it seems it is related to the trust settings of either the ASP.NET process or its dependencies. I have tried changing the trust settings of my ASP.NET application without any success.

Has anyone encountered this error before? It seems like this error is also quite common in code coverage scenarios as well. Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated.